# Moving cursor in a blank paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

Having a bit of trouble with this. Basically, I have a document where I am populating a bookmark, then creating a new line (paragraph) after it, and need to move the cursor to the same position as the start of the bookmark in the above line and enter some text there.

Example:

My name is: [bookmark_name]

....................| <- want my cursor to go here so I can add another name manually

I have the following code:

```
   Sub InsertParagraphMethod()
   Dim MyRange As Object
   Set MyRange = docCaseAssessment.Bookmarks("bookmark_name").Range
   ' Range Example:
   MyRange.InsertParagraphAfter
   MyRange.SetRange Start:=MyRange.Start, End:=MyRange.Start
   MyRange.Select
   Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
   End Sub
```

However, the problem is that since my newly created paragraph is empty, it will keep the cursor at the start of the newly created line.

I was wondering if anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Just have the program add a certain number of spaces where the cursor currently is until you get it to where you want it. You cant move the cursor to a location that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here are a couple of alternatives to @macropod 's suggestion. Personally, I prefer his approach, but perhaps you have reasons it doesn't work in your particular situation:

**Set a TAB stop at the desired position**
Given your description and the code you're using, put the TAB stop in the document containing the bookmark. When you enter a new paragraph at the end of that Range, it should "inherit" the TAB stop.

(Even better: create a style and include the TAB stop in the style.)

Then add a TAB character to the text you insert to move the insertion to the TAB stop.

**Use a two-row, two-column table**
Put the bookmark into the second column, the text preceding it into the first column. Insert the new text into the second column of the second row.

Note about your code: If I'm understanding it correctly you can tighten it up a bit (fewer lines, clearer intent). Something like this would work for my first suggestion:

```
Sub InsertParagraphMethod()
  Dim MyRange As Object

  Set MyRange = docCaseAssessment.Bookmarks("bookmark_name").Range
  ' Range Example:
  MyRange.InsertParagraphAfter
  MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  MyRange.Text = vbTab & "new name"
  'or instead of the last three lines, above:
  'MyRange.InsertAfter Chr(13) & vbTab & "new name"
End Sub
```

If you use Paul's suggestion about formatting the paragraph with the bookmark with a hanging indent and using a new line character (ASCII 11 = Shift+Enter), then more like this:

```
Sub InsertParagraphMethod()
  Dim MyRange As Object
  Set MyRange = docCaseAssessment.Bookmarks("bookmark_name").Range
  ' Range Example:
  myRange.InsertAfter Chr(11) & "new name"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually do what you want, I will take on braX' advise but you have to set the font too.

```
Dim wR As Range
Dim wd As Document: Set wd = ThisDocument

wd.Range(0, 0).Select
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Font.Name = "consolas"

Set wR = wd.Bookmarks("bookmark_name").Range
wR.InsertParagraphAfter
wd.Paragraphs(wd.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text = String$(12, " ")

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bookmark_name"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply format your

My name is: [bookmark_name]

paragraph with a hanging indent equal to the position where [bookmark_name] starts. If you insert a manual line break (Chr 11) at the end of first or any subsequent line in the paragraph, the new line will also start at the same horizontal position as where [bookmark_name] starts. Padding the spacing out as braX suggests is bad practice - Word is not a 1950s typewriter.